# add new child in didBeginContact, but position change to zero?

Tags: sprite-kit

i have a codes like this :

```
    eggSprite *egg = [[eggSprite alloc]init];
    egg.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    [self addChild:egg];
```

if i put this in my update logic , all is well , but if i put it in the didBeginContact: method , it is very strange , it will add this child , but the position will set to (0,0), is that i can not add a node in the didBeginContact: method ? or something i do wrong ?

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{

eggSprite *egg = [[eggSprite alloc]init];
egg.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);

[self addChild:egg];                // <---- after this , the egg's position is change to (0,0) outside this block
}
```

Comment: The didBeginContact method is called when two SKPhysicsBody instances collide with each other and is used to implement collision detection. I think what you are looking for is the -touchesBegan: method.

Comment: yes , i know it . but my logic is that when collide , then do some create node and add to the scene works, not just touch to add .

Comment: So the problem is that the -didBeginContact method is not getting called?

Comment: no , didBeginContac called . the problem is , when i add the child egg , but the egg's position is not set properly . it goes to (0,0) , while actually i set it to (100,100) . sorry for my clumsy description .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding new nodes in `didBeginContact:` is the wrong place to do it. Instead add any new nodes into a MutableArray during your `didBeginContact:` and add them to your world in the `update:` part of the cycle.